# Ruby on Rails map static resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to map static resources, that are located under the `my_assets` folder and contain a lot of different static files (css/js/html/images/json/etc...) under `/my_asset/any_path....`

I don't need any templates and so on... Just serve them as they are under some prefix url.

How I can do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your assets in the `public` folder they will be served as static assets.

Even better is to put your static assets on a CDN so your webserver won't get hit for all those requests for static files.